# Is it possible to install Ubuntu without openssl and libcurl preinstalled?

Tags: kubuntu, curl, openssl, testing

I am looking for an Ubuntu installation that don't have preinstalled libcurl and openssl - for testing.

Is it possible to install Ubuntu without openssl and libcurl preinstalled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The docker image does not have them preinstalled:

```
root@c7722a9cc694:/# dpkg -l openssl
dpkg-query: no packages found matching openssl
root@c7722a9cc694:/# dpkg -l libcurl
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libcurl
root@c7722a9cc694:/#
```